# How many different even 4-digit numbers can be created if digits 0-6 can be used and the first digit is nonzero. Repetition is not allowed.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know that the first digit will be between 1-6 because 0 cannot be chosen but I do not know how to proceed further. How do you solve this?

Comment: If you know what the answer would be without the first-digit restriction, you should tell us.  If not, you should tell us so, too.  This information is "context" that allows answerers help you.

Comment: Consider cases, depending on whether the units digit is $0$ (in which case, there are no further restrictions other than the requirement that the digits be distinct) or another even digit (in which case, the thousands digit cannot be zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: The first digit is even (2, 4, or 6)

In this case, the last digit must be some other even digit, while the middle two digits must be different from each other and from the first and last digits. This gives $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3=180$ 4-digit even numbers with distinct digits less than 7 where the first digit is even.

Case 2: The first digit is odd (1, 3, or 5)

In this case, the last digit can be any even digit, while the middle two digits must still be different from each other and from the first and last digits. This gives $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 4=240$ 4-digit even numbers with distinct digits less than 7 where the first digit is odd.

Adding both cases together, the total number of 4-digit even numbers with distinct digits less than 7 is $180+240=420$.

Comment: in case 2, you used 4 twice so it is not different from last digit which is 4 as well.

Comment: @slow_byte In case 2, the thousands digit may be chosen in three ways since it is odd, the units digits may be chosen in four ways since it is even, the hundreds digit may be chosen in five ways since it must be different from both the thousands digit and the units digit, and the tens digit can be chosen in four ways since it is different from the thousands digit, hundreds digit, and units digit.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to be careful in picking the first digit and the last digit (to ensure your number is even).

Split this in as many cases as you need and then tackle it! For example, start by picking the first digit in 1-6, like you said. Then, how can you pick the last digit?

Comment: So i choose 5 for example as the first digit. Then could I still choose the rest of the numbers between 0-6?

Comment: @slow_byte if repetition is not allowed, now you would only have the digits $0,1,2,3,4,6$